# Plot the derivative of a function with PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have this code:

```
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
x=torch.linspace(-10, 10, 10, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.sum(x**2)
y.backward()
plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), y.detach().numpy(), label='function')
plt.legend()
```

But, I got this error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main problem is that your dimensions do not match. Why do you wan't to use `torch.sum`?

This should work for you:

```py
# %matplotlib inline added this line only for jupiter notebook
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
x = torch.linspace(-10, 10, 10, requires_grad=True)

y = x**2      # removed the sum to stay with the same dimensions
y.backward(x) # handing over the parameter x, as y isn't a scalar anymore
# your function
plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), y.detach().numpy(), label='x**2')
# gradients
plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), x.grad.detach().numpy(), label='grad')
plt.legend()
```

You get a nicer picture though with more steps, I also changed the interval a bit to `torch.linspace(-2.5, 2.5, 50, requires_grad=True)`.

**Edit regarding comment:**

This version plots you the gradients with `torch.sum` included:

```
# %matplotlib inline added this line only for jupiter notebook
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
x = torch.linspace(-10, 10, 10, requires_grad=True)

y = torch.sum(x**2) 
y.backward() 
print(x.grad)
plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), x.grad.detach().numpy(), label='grad')
plt.legend()
```

Output:

```
tensor([-20.0000, -15.5556, -11.1111,  -6.6667,  -2.2222,   2.2222,
      6.6667,  11.1111,  15.5556,  20.0000])
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: @volperossa Now I see what you mean. You're right, that's nonsense. I fixed the respective line, (`x` was plotted instead of `y`). I've removed the wrong pictures as well.
Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to plot the graph of the derivative of `x**2`.

Then, you need to plot the graph between `x` and `x.grad` **NOT** `x` and `y` i.e.

`plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), x.grad.detach().numpy(), label='function')`.